# Invoking an API Gateway Lambda from an Electron/React app using Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, electron, aws-amplify

I have a lambda which is triggered by API gateway, which has many console.logs, including one on the first line of the handler.

If I try to invoke the endpoint from within an electron app using `aws-amplify`:

```js
const response = await API.post(
  "api-name",
  "/endpoint-path",
  {}
).catch(err => {
  console.error("error:", err);
});
console.log("response:", response);
```

I get a 200 response with no errors, but the response is null, the response in the network tab of the dev tools is empty, and I see only the following logs in CloudWatch:

```
START RequestId: <requestId> Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: <requestId>
REPORT RequestId: <requestId> Duration: 2.90 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 41 MB
```

However, if I instead invoke the endpoint in the same spot using `axios`, I get a non-null response, and all of my console.log statements show up in Cloudwatch logs.
Similarly, if I invoke the endpoint directly using Insomnia, it works perfectly fine, I get the expected result and see the expected logs in CloudWatch.
Invoking the endpoint using `aws-amplify` in a React Web App works fine as well.

It just seems to be the combination of `electron` and `aws-amplify` that don't seem to play nicely together. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Do you really need to make a `POST` request instead of `GET`?

Comment: Yes, this is pared down for the example

Comment: The example shows reading the response in a `then` block

API.post(apiName, path, myInit).then(response => {
    // Add your code here
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
});

Comment: @BrianMcCall you can use `async/await` to `await` a promise as I have above instead of using `then`

Comment: is your lambda function async?
exports.handler = async function(event, context) {
...

Comment: It is, but that is completely irrelevant to this question anyway